# Proving $F_{\sigma}$ set

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, baire-category

I am reading a paper on "On some properties of Baire-$1$ functions". In Proposition $8$, it states that it is straight forward to prove that $E_n$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ set. I would like to know how do we prove that $E_n$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ set? Sorry I am a beginner in these concepts, and would appreciate some help! Thank you.

[image: Proving each En is an Fsigma set]

Comment: Do you know what an $F_\sigma$ set is?

Comment: I only know that it is a countable union of closed sets.

Comment: take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function)

Comment: Are you aware that $\{ x\in\mathbb{R}: \vert f(x)\vert \leq \alpha \}$ is closed?

Comment: Does closed mean bounded? I have an idea that |()| ≤  can probably be expressed as a union of closed sets. How do I show mathematically that f(x) < n and -n < f(x) are  sets?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Your set need not be closed for a Baire 1 function $f$.